# Display image while page onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my `HTML` page i use certain option onload , processing, Loading external `.txt` file in page since this process takes some time to load i need to display image until process is over

and i found this script

```
<script>
      // Put an animated GIF image insight of content
      $("#content").empty().html('<img src="http://www.website.com/images/loading.gif" />');

      // Make AJAX call
      $("#content").load("http://website.com/page.php")
      </script>
```

since i use many process like page onload processing loading txt file

So how do i reduce page transparency and display image (.gif) on the above mention process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working CSS blowing bubble loading spinner. You don't even need to upload anything else. Just simply target a field which you want to show the spinner. And Use `.show()` and `.hide()` to show and hide spinner when it necessarily.

[Reference](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/)

```js
  $('.loader').show(); //show
  $("#content").load("http://website.com/page.php") {

    $('.loader').delay(1000).hide(); //hide

  }
```

```css
.loader:before,

.loader:after,

.loader {

  display: none;

  border-radius: 50%;

  width: 2.5em;

  height: 2.5em;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;

  animation-fill-mode: both;

  -webkit-animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;

  animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;

}

.loader {

  margin: 8em auto;

  font-size: 10px;

  position: relative;

  text-indent: -9999em;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.16s;

  animation-delay: 0.16s;

}

.loader:before {

  left: -3.5em;

}

.loader:after {

  left: 3.5em;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.32s;

  animation-delay: 0.32s;

}

.loader:before,

.loader:after {

  content: '';

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

}

@-webkit-keyframes load7 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em #ffffff;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0 #FFF;

  }

}

@keyframes load7 {

  0%, 80%, 100% {

    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em #ffffff;

  }

  40% {

    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0 #FFF;

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Update:

Another way of doing it is:

- Add html element where you will show the loader. (e.g #example)
- Add `display: hidden` to `#example`
- Before you want to load or on load add `.show()` to `#example`
- Ajax call
- After request is called `.hide()` `#example`

Comment: what does this line means `$("#content").load("http://website.com/page.php")`the current page or the page that is loaded

Comment: You are asking me about your code? :) It's creating an AJAX request. Please follow [`jQuery AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i found above code at stack overflow can you help me i need to display gif when `onload, loading txt file, loading external php`

Comment: Updated the question, based on your logic.